# How to create a secure login from javascript to json WCF Service?

Tags: javascript, json, wcf, authentication

I've create an android application using Phonegap + jQuery Mobile and a web service using WCF + JSON response. I want to create a login form for my android application then send the login data by JSON and do authentication in my WCF Service. How to create a secure login for this condition?

Comment: Is using HTTPS a possibility?  That's likely the easiest approach.

Comment: I don't know, how to using that?

Comment: You need to have an SSL certificate for your domain and have your server set aside a separate port to listen for https traffic (usually http is port 80 and https is 443). If you have a hosting company managing your server setup, call them up and see what they say. If you think it might be supported already, try just calling your WCF service with an https prefix (try it in a browser with developer tools open/enabled) and see what comes back.

Comment: @PatrickM okay, I'll try your suggestion. Thank you :)